# Single layer perceptron: incorporating bias

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

How would I go about adding to [this code](https://github.com/llSourcell/Make_a_neural_network/blob/master/demo.py) to include bias in the network? Is it as simple as adding a + 1 to the forward pass in the `think(self, inputs)`method? How would I generalise this solution to a multi-layer perceptron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as there is only 1 neuron you can add 1 directly to the return statement of think() function.

```
def think(self, inputs):
    return self.__sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights) + 1)
```

Remember never initialize weights to zeros! You can always do it with the bias values. For a particular layer, the dimension of bias vector would be [number_of_neurons_in_the_layer, 1]

```
class NeuralNetwork():
def __init__(self):
    random.seed(1)
    self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1
    # Now you have to initialize bias
    # You can either keep it 0 or and random number
    self.bias = random.randn(1,1)
    # Here as there is only 1 neuron, dimension becomes (1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the bias need to be updated at all as training progresses?

Comment: Yes, once you find loss or the cost function after the final layer(assuming its a deep neural network) you need to come backwards, consequently changing all the weights and biases. That's what is called "Learning" I.e updating weights and biases using backpropagation